# C++ API: Modifing internal objects

Tags: c++, api-design

I've got two related questions.
At the moment I am designing/writing a C++ API, in which I need to be able to modify an object that is held by another object.

It is comparable to this example:

```
class Bar
{
    public:
        Bar(int x) : num(x){}

        void setNum(int x)
        {
            num = x;
        }

        int getNum()
        {
            return num;
        }

    private:
        int num;
};

class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo() = default;

        void setBar(std::unique_ptr<Bar> newBar)
        {
            bar = std::move(newBar);
        }

        Bar* getBar()
        {
            return bar.get();
        }

    private:
        std::unique_ptr<Bar> bar;
};
```

The class `Foo` takes ownership of `Bar`, however, `Bar` must be able to be modified.
Here, `Foo` is the main class the user would interact with.
Whilst `Bar` could be considered more as a data type, which changes the output of `Foo`.

Is the solution of returning a raw pointer to `Bar` the preferred option?
I have the feeling, that this brakes the encapsulation which is a no-go for API design.
My googling efforts haven't given me a concrete answer to exactly this problem yet.
But I might just be looking with the wrong search terms.

The second part to this question is, how this example would change, if `Bar` would be stored in a container in `Foo`.
Would I return a pointer to the whole container, an iterator for the container ...?

Comment: Is there a strong reason to return non-const pointer from `getBar`?

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing what Foo and Bar are supposed to do. The answers to all of your questions really depend on the given context. I definitely would not return a raw pointer, though. You can return a reference, that way it's clear that ownership remains with Foo.

Comment: Perhaps `Foo` should publish a full interface of what kinds of things a client would like to do with `Bar`, that way `Bar` is fully encapsulated inside `Foo`.

Comment: in some sense `getBar` breaks encapsulation, the return type is just a secondary effect

Comment: I wish there was some universal guideline to apply here, but without further details there simply is no such thing. You have to make up your mind what users of your API are allowed to do and then encode that as best as possible. Should they have full control over all operations on `Bar`? Your code is fine. Should it be more fine-grained? Then you need to specify that "grainedness" before looking into the C++ way of expressing it.

Comment: Your `Foo` basically only wraps what `std::unique_ptr<Bar>` do it by itself. It also owns the `Bar` object, and return it by reference via `operator*` or by pointer via `get`. What is the purpose of `Foo` in the first place?

Comment: @IgorG what benefit should a const pointer have? It is returning a copy of the pointer anyway.

Comment: @t.niese it could prevent the client from modifying the `Bar` directly, forcing them to make and set a new instance on each modification.

Comment: @IgorG I wouldn't want to set a new instance for smaller modifications,

Comment: @pingleit is any kind of synchronization required in accessing the `Bar` instance from `Foo` and from the client code? I mean, what if the client wanted to make _two_ small modifications to `Bar`? Is it acceptable that `Foo` might catch `Bar` in its intermediate state?

Comment: @IgorG so you mean a pointer to const and not a const pointer?

Comment: @t.niese yes. Sorry if my wording wasn't precise.

Comment: @IgorG Yes that would be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the solution of returning a raw pointer to Bar the preferred option?

It's a solution and not necessarily a bad one. Returning a reference would be preferable in cases where the object always exists (not in this case since `Foo`'s default constructor doesn't create a `Bar`).

Some programmers prefer to use a wrapper for bare pointers (such as `observer_ptr`, which has been proposed to the standard) to distinguish it from a pointer whose purpose is to iterate an array, or from owning bare pointers (latter of which should be avoided).

> I have the feeling, that this brakes the encapsulation

Your whole premise is to break the encapsulation since you want to *"modify internal objects"*. If you want to avoid breakage of encapsulation, then you may need to change the design further up so that you don't need to modify internal objects (externally).

A solution that doesn't break encapsulation is to provide a specific interface to `Foo` for modification, such as:

```
void Foo::transmogrify_bar(int gadgets) {
    bar->transmofgrify(gadgets);
}
```

Whether this encapsulation is useful for your API is another matter. In some cases it is essential, in others it doesn't matter much.

> if Bar would be stored in a container in Foo. Would I return a pointer to the whole container, an iterator for the container ...?

Would you want the client to be able to modify the container (add, remove elements)?

This is breaking the encapsulation further. Instead, you could have `begin` and `end` iterators that don't allow modification of the container itself, which brings you to an equivalent encapsulation of the pointer return in the case of single object.

You could provide only const iterators, and add iterator as an argument to `transmogrify` to keep encapsulation of modifying `Bar`.

Finally, for full encapsulation, you would need to use PIMPL pattern to hide `Bar` completely.

Comment: Alternatively, you can return a reference and if the object does not exist, throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you worry about `getBar` breaking the encapsulation, then you should also see `void setBar(std::unique_ptr<Bar> newBar)` as such a breakage.

Because allowing to set `bar` from outside does make the knowledge about `bar` possibly none exclusive to `Foo` and the one passing `Bar` to `Foo` might have still the possibility to modify the `bar` so `Foo` can no do any assumptions about the state of `Bar`, as it could change anytime.

On the other hand, if you only want to have reading access to `Bar` trough `Foo` then a `const Bar* getBar()` or `const Bar& getBar()` would not break the encapsulation that much, because `getBar` would not allow changing `Bar`.